# Add list style back to li tag atfer visibility:collapse;

Tags: html, css

I have This `html`:

**HTML**

```
<li>
   <a>Title</a>
(0)
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
   visibility:collapse;
}
li a {
   visibility:visible;
}
```

The `CSS` works and hide the "0" out of the a tag.

The problem is that the list `style` of the li does not come back after `visibility:collapse`;

How could i set the that where will be list style back ?

Adding to a tag list style didn't work well because its make the bullet point of list style a link itself.

I have access only to style.css so can't add a span around the 0.

Comment: When exactly do you want the `visibility:collapse;` to revert back?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you collapse all the list, so you hide its style.

- A solution can be to put the element in a span and collapse it.

---

```
<li>
   <a>Title</a>
    <span class='collapse'>(0)</span>
</li>
```

---

```
li .collapse{
   visibility:collapse;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jb0yzewt/2/

Comment: Have access only to style.css

Answer (score 0):

How about using the pseudo `:before` element of the `li`. Something like this.

```css
li.fake {
  visibility:collapse;

}
li.fake:before {
  content: '\2022';
  visibility:visible;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: sub;
  margin: 0 3px 0 -15px

}

li a {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<li class="fake">
   <a href="">Title</a>
(0)
</li>

<li class="real">
   <a href="">Title</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Tried it,  its not the default list style of the page,  just a small dot

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. You can style the pseudo element just like any other element, so make it like the default list style type.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit (new Answer):

Your edit makes me understand your desire a little better.
To get back the list-style to the a element how about applying

```
display: list-item;
list-style-type: disc;
```

to the "a" - elements?

---

### Old answer (getting back the "0"):

The "0" is hidden because its inside the li not the a element.
In order to make it visible you have to put the "0" in another tag a span for example.

What you could to is insert it into the "a"-element and apply

```
"pointer-events: none;"
```

Doing that will prevent the user from clicking on the element. 
Bear in mind that this is not fully supported across all browsers.

To  keep it more flexible and so that you don't have to include the numbers in the markup **I would suggest a pseudo-element**.

```
    body { 
/* ideally you want to initialize the counter on the parent element of your li elements. */
    counter-reset: listElementCounter;
}

li {
    counter-increment: listElementCounter;   /* increment the counter for every li */  
}

    li::after {
        content: counter(listElementCounter); /* output the Number */
        visibility: visible;
    }
```